# Illustrator: How to drag-to-select objects atop another object

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have several objects atop a rectangular backdrop, and I'd like to select them all via drag-selection (ie, creating a rectangle selection box around them).

Problem is: anywhere I can start the rectangle, the backdrop gets selected and my dragging just moves that.

Wondering if there's another solution besides the ones I've already deduced:

1. start selection off-artboard or on a locked object, then deselect items i don't want
2. be more judicious about locking background items (not an unworkable solution, but inconvenient in this project.

I'm asking mainly b/c, in Inkscape, holding down Ctrl makes your dragging automatically a selection box, avoiding this problem.  My hope is that there's something similar in illustrator.

Thanks!

Comment: Go to Outline mode.

Comment: Why not lock the unwanted item before selection of the items on top? (cmd+2)

Comment: @cclark413 this particular project makes that extra step kinda inefficient, but that may be because i learned on inkscape and am just having difficulty adapting my workflow

thanks jongware, i hadn't played with outline mode before.  that did the trick & then some.

Answer (score 3):

As described by @jongware in comments to OP, working in outline mode obviated this problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CoolSelection. It's a plugin tool for Illustrator.
It's similar to the Selection Tool (V), but it selects only objects **fully inside** the selection rectangle.
https://www.cool-selection.com
This answer was written by the author of CoolSelection.